# Como faço para mostrar miniaturas de arquivos da minha aplicação no explorer do Windows?

Tags: windows

Tenho uma aplicação que usa um formato próprio de arquivo (por exemplo, uma extensão .xyz, sendo um formato próprio da minha aplicação).

Noto que quando tenho um PDF, o Explorer mostra miniaturas, Quando tenho vídeos e imagens, também. Gostaria de ter a mesma funcionalidade para os arquivos .xyz mencionados, associados à minha aplicação.

Qual é o caminho para gerar estas miniaturas, de forma a fazer o Windows exibi-las? É alguma API específica?

Comment: reordenei um pouco as informações, caso não goste da edição, pode alterar, ou mesmo reverter para sua versão anterior pelo histórico, disponível em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/157516/revisions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O Windows Explorer é o responsável pela exibição dos ícones e miniaturas, e tem várias funcionalidades que podem ser adicionadas por aplicações de terceiros. O que você busca, são as...

### Shell Extensions

As *Shell Extensions*, como o nome diz, podem ser implementadas para acrescentar funcionalidades no OS.

Basicamente são implementadas como interfaces COM, e os pontos de entrada são definidos na API do Windows.

Para C#, um ponto de partida é este:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpShell

Alguns exemplos das funcionalidades:

#### Miniaturas de arquivos

Podem ser associadas a determinadas extensões ou CLSID, que é o que você está buscando.

[image: Miniatura]

#### *Preview Handlers*

Seriam um complemento relevante para as miniaturas, já que vai fazer as miniaturas de ícones, seria bom aproveitar a lógica para mostrar no painel de visualização da própria janela também:

[image: Preview handler]

#### *Overlay* de ícones

Programas de sincronismo com armazenamento externo, ou aplicações como TortoiseGit, podem exibir um pequeno indicador sobre o ícone da aplicação, para mostrar se o arquivo está sincronizado, por exemplo;

[image: Overlay]

#### *Property sheets*

São páginas novas nas propriedades de arquivo: tem extensões para o Windows que permitem alteração em datas de arquivos, detecção de *streams* alternativos NTFS, entre outras;

[image: Property sheets]

Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre a implementação propriamente dita, pois depende muito da linguagem usada.

Como leitura complementar, tem uma série muito interessante no Code Project, feita para .NET, neste endereço (que é de onde vieram as imagens da resposta):

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563114/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Thumbnail-Handlers